# Inserting html table data with php & mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to display data from a MySQL table in a html table using php, I've looked at a few tutorials online including answers on StackOverflow... I've implemented it the way said tutorials have described but I am getting no output.

```
<table border="1px solid black" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
                <th>Sunday</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <?php
                include('dbConnect.php');
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM nurses";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['idno'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
</table>
```

I know that my db connection is successful as I test for this. All that's getting output is the `<thead>` and then nothing. I don't understand why this isn't working :/

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated by the way, stick with mysqli_*

Comment: All that;s getting outputted is the "header row", I assume you mean?

Comment: Connection being what; `mysqli_`, `mysql_`, PDO? Do this `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Plus, is your file `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: *"If possible, could somebody help me with a new related problem?"* - Sure, [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You shouldn't modify your question with it being solved and asking what should be a new question. I did a rollback to the original post.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah thanks that's how I managed to fix it :)

Comment: ok @Fred-ii- I'll make a new question... just gonna have to wait 90 minutes unfortunately :/ although maybe I can figure it before then... just maybe.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how the Stack system works. ;) I saved you from someone flagging your question ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay thanks :) getting used to how stackoverflow works too... I'll get googling in the meantime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say you have tested this, then there should be no error when trying to execute `mysql_query`. To be sure that any data is being fetched though, please do a `var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` after the `$result = mysql_query($sql);` line to see if at least a single line is being returned from the database. Additionally, you should not use `mysql_*` functions anymore since they are being deprecated. 
Check here how it works. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

In the case that `var_dump` returns at least a single result, then most likely `$row['idno']` is not a proper column name in your results (you can see what is in the array from the var_dump)

Comment: Thanks @zigi I did indeed have an error somewhere in my connection, not sure how I was able to echo that the connection was successful.

Comment: Please don't forget to select a correct answer/vote. Additionally, I strongly suggest that you start using PDO instead of `mysql` methods. Check here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Here is also a really good SO article about why you should not use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php